Is it possible to redirect only certain requests to real websites to a webserver on localhost?
I've started to experiment with nginx on my windows 11 machine.
What I wanted is the following:

Given is some real website.
All requests that start with realwebsite.com/magic, should instead go to localhost:3000
But all other requests that start with realwebsite.com should go to the real website

What I have tried:

First, I set up a server on localhost:3000 and confirmed it is working.
Edited my hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and added 127.0.0.1 realwebsite.com
Edited nginx.conf by adding:

`server {
listen 80;
server_name realwebsite.com;
    # send magic requests to localhost server
location /magic{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

    # send all other requests to the real website       
location / {
    proxy_pass https://www.realwebsite.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}       

}`
Expected Behevioour:
when i visit realwebsite.com/magic, browser should display some test.html file
Actual Behaviour:
Site cant be reached and the server running on localhost:3000 doesn't log any get request when entering realwebsite.com/magic
But when I visit localhost:3000 directly, the server does log the get request
My local server is simply set up like this:
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const BASE_DIR = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Projects\\test\\server';


app.use('/magic', express.static(BASE_DIR));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url}`);
    next();
});

app.get('/magic/:filename', (req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.join(BASE_DIR, req.params.filename);
    res.download(filePath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(404).send('File not found!');
        }
    });
});

app.get('/magic', (req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test.html');
    res.sendFile(filePath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(err.status).send('File not found!');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});


It looks like you're missing the slash at the end of the location and proxy_pass settings. The following configuration works for me.
Nginx is configured to run on port 8000 while the localhost server is configured to run on port 8080.
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen       8000;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /magic/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://www.google.com/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }   
}

=== ORIGINAL ANSWER ===
It sounds like Nginx may be running somewhere other than on your local computer.
Since you're using Nginx as a proxy (not redirecting), Nginx itself needs access to the proxy_pass host. If Nginx isn't running locally, then it doesn't have access to localhost.
Think about it this way:
Request: Browser => Nginx => http://localhost:3000
Response: Browser <= Nginx <= http://localhost:3000

localhost is a loopback to 127.0.0.1, which is not a publicly accessible IP address.
You have two options:

Run Nginx locally. I'm not sure if this allows you to work the way you need to.
If you have a publicly accessible static IP address for your computer, you could use that in Nginx instead of localhost.

I hope that helps.

I downloaded nginx as a zip file and extracted it on C:/ and then I ran the .exe after editing the nginx.conf. Is that wrong? I don’t really get what you mean by „it may not be running on your local computer“

realwebsite.com has to be one of two things (1) localhost or (2) a domain or subdomain that's is configured to point to 127.0.0.1. It sounds like you're running Nginx locally, so you need to ensure your requests are hitting your Nginx server (including any port that may be configured).

Idk if I'm getting something wrong so let me give you some more context: I'm trying to load a local script in the developer console at some website like so:
let worker = new Worker('path/to/local/script.js') which is not allowed in chrome but I thought it might be possible if I fake the path by setting up a proxy and make it seem like I load the script from the website, when in reality I load it from my local computer.

That additional context was very helpful. Rather than using a proxy, you should be able to load that file from the same domain. What I'd suggest is to add 127.0.0.1 local.realwebsite.com to your \WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file. This file is, essentially, a local DNS file. Then, from realwebsite.com, you can load a file from local.realwebsite.com. Let me know if that works for you.

Unfortunately, it didn't work either. e.g. if I try adding 127.0.01 local.google.com
and on google.com I run:
let worker = new Worker(https://local.google.com/myscript.js)
I still get the SecurityError. Or does my local nodejs server need to be configured for port 443 instead of 8080 ?

I updated the answer after setting this up and confirming locally. Let me know if that revised answer works for you.

I appreciate your efforts. Sadly, it still doesnt work for me :/ I also added my server code to this post. The server doesnt even log a request when i visit google.com/magic or google.com/magic/somefile.js. Maybe this problem is related to my pc or something.
What browser and OS were you using?

I just ran your code and realized that your Express configuration requires magic to be in the path for both of the routes, while your Nginx configuration removes it. You need to either change the proxy_pass value to proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/magic/ or change your Express app to accept requests at the root path without magic in the path.

Also worth noting that you have to go to localhost:8000 in your browser to load the Google website. localhost:8000/magic is what would proxy your request locally to localhost:8080/magic. Google doesn't have a /magic path so going their directly won't work.
